# Which tag to use for series convergence testing?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

It would seem both the [convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence) and [divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) tags are frequently used for questions concerning the convergence of a series. I would've thought the [convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence) tag would be more appropriate and that the [divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) tag would be more reserved for things such as using summation methods to evaluate divergent series, but it would seem the latter tag is used quite frequently with questions concerning the convergence of a series with no regard for evaluating them.

Are they both usable? If not, I would suggest making the [divergent-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divergent-series) tag info more clear.

Comment: Related: [How should questions about deciding convergence/divergence of a series be tagged?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20959)

Comment: Perhaps the description of [tag:divergent-series] should be rewritten as something akin to `For questions on divergent series, and how to deal with divergent series using summation methods such as Ramanujan or Abel summation.`

Comment: I'd say that the tag ([tag:divergent-series]) and ([tag:summation-method]) are very close each other. Maybe they could be synonyms or (divergent-series) could be completely replaced by (summation-method)? (Another tag which has an overlap with this topic is ([tag:regularization]).)